# Deploy spring boot web app on external linux server and access on windows browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I've a spring boot app deployed on an external linux server.

When I tried to run this app , I used netstat -tulpn to check

```
0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      xxx/java
```

I can see that the tomcat in this app is running well.

My question is, how can I redirect the localhost url's to test.webapp.test.fr (for example) on my windows browser ? (assuming that roots/proxy are open)

application.properties :

```
server.port=8081
server.servlet.context-path=/ui-web
classic-url=http://localhost:8080/webclient
authentication-url=http://localhost:8080/webclient
data-url=http://localhost:8082/data-web
base-url=http://localhost:8082/data-web
```

Thank you for help